# PHP : 2MB of JSON object vs frequent AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

In the application there is PHP form mentioned below:

```
<html>
<body>
   <br/>
   <br><section style="min-width: 500px; margin: 1px auto;">
   <form align="centre" name="showq" id="showq" method="post" action=demo.php>
       <fieldset><legend> Demo</legend>
       <table>
          <tr><td id="one" colspan="2"><div>ABCD</div></td></tr>
          <tr><td id="two" colspan="2"><div>EFGH</div></td></tr>
          <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="pre" id="pre" value="pre" ></input>&nbsp;
         <input type="submit" name="nxt" id="nxt" value="nxt"></input>&nbsp;
         <input type="submit" name="getvalfromserver" id="getvalfromserver" value="GETVALFRMSERVER"></input></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
     </form></fieldset></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently on every click of "pre" or "nxt"  or "getvalfromserver" it submits PHP form and refreshes the entire page and populate values in `<TD>` with id "one" and "two" 
Data is stored on server as two dimensional PHP Array

```
Ex: 
Array { 
    ABCD, EFGH  - *First array element* 
    IJKL, MNOP
    QRST, UVWX 
    and so on...
}
```

I want to avoid this page refresh; after reading other posts in stackoverflow ; i thought of two options:

1. Option One - Pass PHP array on client side as JSON
2. Option Two - Keep PHP Array on server and on button click send AJAX request to server to receive required value.

In My case Size of PHP array can be upto 2 MB of data. user click "nxt" "pre" navigation concurrently and very frequently.

Is there any third option other than two mentioned above? 
If NO, Can you please suggest; out of two options ; which one is better suited from performance perspective ?

Comment: "Can you please suggest; out of two options ; which one is better suited from performance perspective" - that sounds too subjective to me.

Comment: 2MB is not much. jQuery is 50 times larger. Send it at once.

Comment: Can you see all this data on the page at once?

Comment: jQuery is 50 times larger than 2MB?  2KB yes, but not 2MB

Comment: Actually if somebody doesn't have a fast connection it can take quite a while to download those 2MB, I would suggest loading that data in chunks.

Comment: @tymeJV ; NO : at given time only one record is displayed (max 200 kb)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty ; Sorry I'm not able to understand comment; Size of PHP array can go upto 2MB

Comment: @crisbeto ; So you suggest to go for AJAX option?

Comment: @JanDvorak ; I've received some good suggestions in this forum so posted this question; Kindly correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Your HTML code can be improved a lot...

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to refresh your page every time you send/receive info.

Comment: Forget the connection speed for a moment. I see another issue here: will the client (the browser) be able to handle 2MB of data in memory? Most modern browsers on desktop likely yes, but I can't say the same for older browsers or mobile ones...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which application server you are using, you can easily turn on gzip compression on JSON and reduce the size down to something like 600 KB ( I am assuming this is all text)

We have done this on apache and performance improved significantly on our one page, no refresh ExtJS application

1) You would json_encode the 2 dimensional array first.

2) Then enable compression on your apache server using the mod_deflate module
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/json
```

3) at the thick client, you can use JSON.parse() or similar functionality to parse out the data

Comment: We are using LAMP Stack with Apache webserver. So, as per your past experiece, we can gzip 2 dimentional array on webserver and then pass it as JSON object on client? Then Unzip it on client and use in application. Do you've any useful docuemnt pointer to guide for same?

Comment: You can also GZIP the text in PHP, without loading any module in the server. See: http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/zlib.examples.php

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you REALLY need to do is create a way to paginate the data.  Particularly since it seems you only need a few data points at a time.  So let's say your array looks something like this:

```
Array(
   [0] => Array ('ABCD', 'EFGH'),
   [1] => Array ('IJKL', 'MNOP'),
   ...
   [n] => Array ('foo', 'bar')
)
```

You are already VERY well set up for pagination.  You can easily determine the number of pages by doing:

```
$array_size = count($array);
```

You can also individually retrieve any given array of values be going directly to it's index.  So let's say I wanted page #100 of this data set (like would happen if I pressed `nxt` button 99 times.  You can easily get this as follows:

```
// here we assume this page value would be posted by AJAX as parameter 'page'
// note: GET may also be suitable as method here
// note: you would also probably need to validate this is an integer like value that is passed
$page_index = $_POST['page'] - 1;
// get array at this index value 
$page_to_return = $array[$page_index];
// encode to JSON to return to calling script
echo json_encode($page_to_return);
```

This mean in javascript you just need to know the value of the page you are on, such that when requesting the previous or next page, you can decrement/increment that value, pass it to the PHP script, and get the "page" at that index for updating into the UI.

This allows you to only pass around one tiny portion of you array at any given page request.  You can even cache the values in javascript if you like such that a user going backwards and forwards of the same "pages" would not require additional calls to the server. Or depending on your user behavior, you might even preload your first X number of pages in javascript on first page load and then request additional pages as needed.